# How to take link from onclickvalue in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, onclick

Need help scrubbing a link to an image that is stored in the `onclick=` value.
I do this, but I stopped how to remove everything in onclick except for the link.

`<a onclick="ShowEnlargedImagePreview( 'https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/794261971268711656/69C39CF2A2BBCDDC7C04C17DF1E88A6ED875DBE7/' );"></a>`

```
links = soup.find('div', class_='workshopItemPreviewImageMain')
links = links.findChild('a', attrs={'onclick': re.compile("^https://")})
```

But nothing is output.

```
links = soup.find('div', class_='workshopItemPreviewImageMain')
links = links.findChild('a')
links = links.get("onclick")
```

The entire value of onclick is displayed:

```
howEnlargedImagePreview( 'https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/794261971268711656/69C39CF2A2BBCDDC7C04C17DF1E88A6ED875DBE7/' )
```

But only a link is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your regular expression.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'''(?P<quote>['"])(?P<href>https?://.+?)(?P=quote)''')

data = '''
<div class="workshopItemPreviewImageMain">
<a onclick="ShowEnlargedImagePreview( 'https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/794261971268711656/69C39CF2A2BBCDDC7C04C17DF1E88A6ED875DBE7/' );"></a>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', class_='workshopItemPreviewImageMain')

links = div.find_all('a', {'onclick': pattern})

for a in links:
    print(pattern.search(a['onclick']).group('href'))
```